# ngFor loop and ngIf loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I am a beginner in TypeScript. I am trying to create a loop to iterate all my series: ngFor = "let series of seriesList", and to display that have their modality equal to 'CT': ngIf = "series.instance.modality == 'CT'

I try this :

```
<series [series]=series *ngFor="let series of seriesList; let i = index">
  <series *ngIf="series.instance.modality == 'CT'"></series>
</series>
```

And this :

```
<series [series]=series 
        *ngFor="let series of seriesList; 
        let i = index; 
        *ngIf="series.instance.modality == 'CT'">
</series>
```

///////////////EDIT//////////////:

I try this :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="series.instance.modality == 'CT'">
  <series [series]="series" *ngFor="let series of seriesList; let i = index">
  </series>
</ng-container>
```

But that can not work because I have to do my loop for before my if i think ..

Comment: then switch ngFor and ngIf (ngFor on ng-container and ngIf on the component)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer
Like this : `<ng-container [series]="series" *ngFor="let series of seriesList; let i = index">
      <series  *ngIf="series.instance.modality == 'CT'">
      </series>
    </ng-container>`

Comment: Yes, but `[series]="series"` on `<ng-container` is pointless.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer
Thanks for your answer :)